# Change output voice frequency

Tags: audio, output

My friend can not hear all voice frequencies. I need software that brings all frequency spectrums to a specific band.

Is there any software do this? I mean change all output sound frequencies to be on a specific frequency band.

**NOTE:** Also notice that I need a frequency changer and not cutter.

Comment: What is required is some form of _mixer_ and/or filter. Changing sound features is sometimes a _post-processing_ option in some specific software(music playback). Specify maybe if that is only to be used in realtime with a mic, for all sounds the computer produces, or on preexisting audio files. I personally do not understand your last sentence. A cutter? You mean you don't want a sound editor? A utility like [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) can alter also a stream; see in this [context](http://askubuntu.com/q/421947), which may help.